# Using instruments to detect-CFString leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app is crashes sometimes, without any log errors.

I am using instruments-leaks/alloctations, to find whats wrong.

There is a linear growth in allocations in some point.

If i check who is responsible, i can see there is one main thing:

```
 CFString (immutable) Responsible Caller: [NSBundle mainBundle]
```

I never `allocate` string in my code.
I have read here , that it has to do with my assets, that are in group and not in folder.
Is that correct ?
Can anyone give me direction to put my finger on the specific object in instrument that cause that growth ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: What makes you think memory leaks are causing the crash?

Comment: The linear growth in allocations when i am not touching the app at all.